# How to debug chaincode? LedgerError - ResourceNotFound

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I got this I believe pretty common error `"..LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found" .`

To make it simple, this is what I have:

1. Try simple chaincode, the given `chaincode_example02.go` codes
2. turned off security hence no CA `(CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=false CORE_SECURITY_PRIVACY=falss)`
3. 1 peer node only (using 0.5 version), it is a peer docker image
4. run in dev mode

This is how I deployed the code in dev mode, pls do verify if the cli is correct:

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:30303 ./chaincode_example02
```

and it shows

```
'Received REGISTERED, ready for invocations'
```

Now trying to query it, pls do verify if this cli is correct :

```
peer chaincode query -n mycc -c '{"Function": "query", "Args": ["b"]}'
```

but the error returned were :

```
Error: Error querying chaincode: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for chaincode_example02 - LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found)"
```

Any idea?  I checked all logs under `/var` but didn't find anything useful, also checked `/var/hyperledger` and did see some updates under `/var/hyperledger/production/db`.

This trial seems pretty straight forwards but surprise to get an error.

.. so how should I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

The following command,

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:30303 ./chaincode_example02
```

doesn't `deploy` the chaincode, it simply start and register the chaincode with the validating peer.

Once it is registered, you need to`deploy` and then `invoke` it before you can `query`.

As described [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md#chaincode-deploy-via-cli-and-rest),

> First, send a chaincode deploy transaction, only once, to the
>   validating peer. The CLI connects to the validating peer using the
>   properties defined in the core.yaml file. Note: The deploy transaction
>   typically requires a path parameter to locate, build, and deploy the
>   chaincode. However, because these instructions are specific to local
>   development mode and the chaincode is deployed manually, the name
>   parameter is used instead.

```
peer chaincode deploy -n mycc -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'
```

Once it is deployed, you can invoke it as many times you want and then `query` the invoked transaction,

To `invoke`,

```
peer chaincode invoke -l golang -n mycc -c '{"Function": "invoke", "Args": ["a", "b", "10"]}'
```

and to `query`,

```
peer chaincode query -l golang -n mycc -c '{"Function": "query", "Args": ["b"]}'
```

Also make sure that you have `peer` running in one terminal, running the chaincode in 2nd terminal, while deploying, invoking and querying transactions from the third one.

Comment: Ok,I did a deploy, it return a long number, then an invoke again it return some number, then finally did a query but it still return the same error. Now what?  A few more questions: 1) is -n option value should be 'mycc' for deploy, invoke and query? 2) is there any log files that i can look? 3) where is the standard output file, that is where 'fmt.Printf' output to?

Comment: -n is meant to be a transaction id however when you are running in development mode you dont need it. are you running in development mode ?

Comment: Yes dev mode, can you pls answer three of my questions first.  Also I did see that a new docker container has been created for my deployed chaincode .. so pls advice what's next?

Comment: could you please modify your question and add all those "numbers" that you are seeing when deploying and invoking the transaction ? kindly add everything including the final error that you are seeing...please add the version of fabric you are using as well

Comment: p.s: if you start your peer with `--logging-level` set to `debug` you can see all the logged data you want.`--logging-level=debug`, https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/logging-control.md

Comment: I don't know what 'numbers' you were talking about, if you are referring to chaincode id returned after deployed then it is 24169c1fdb6d6b4b70e304e6a8222e825d48c306de706367a8cb2739a574f409d255d74c3d46c44b16a0e06dcddc391cf4a8682f6ccbae958a07cce893de9aee.  The error message is when making a query, the error message  already stated in the first main body of the question which is "Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for ... LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found)"