# Deploying chaincode successful. But, cannot query - says Ledgernotfound

Tags: blockchain, chain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have started a peer and membersrvc container with docker compose. They have started successfully. I deploying example02 chaincode from CLI (tried REST also). I get a success message. When i try to query the chaincode, i am getting Error when querying chaincode: Error:Failed to launch chaincode spec(Could not get deployment transaction for mycc - LedgerError - ResourceNotFound: ledger: resource not found[)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuwrE.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to deploy the chaincode in dev mode, you first need to register the chaincode.
(Registration is only required in dev mode and not for production mode)

To register your chaincode on windows 10 machine in docker container :

1. open command prompt and go to bash shell using docker command

   docker exec -it [peer container id] /bin/bash
2. Browse to chainocde directory and register it using

   CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:7051 ./chaincode_example02

Now you would see register successful message  : “Received REGISTERED, ready for invocations” and is ready to deploy, invoke and query in dev mode

Note: Leave the window as with register handler open, closing it would deregister the chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for a few minutes after the chaincode deployment might produce different results when querying.  As described [here](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-issues/issues/20), it could take a couple of minutes for chaincode to deploy.  Another suggestion mentioned is to review the chaincode container log to determine if there are problems communicating with a peer.

It is also possible that the chaincode deployment was not successful.  The log for the peer where the chaincode deployment was initiated could be reviewed to determine if this provides any insight.

There are also a couple of prior posts that are similar and might help.

- [How to debug chaincode? LedgerError - ResourceNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730368/how-to-debug-chaincode-ledgererror-resourcenotfound)
- [Hyperledger : Deploying chaincode successful. But, cannot query - says ResourceNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743046/hyperledger-deploying-chaincode-successful-but-cannot-query-says-resourcen)

Comment: Hello Andrew.!! thanks for giving reply to me. i am new to Block chain technology. can you pls tell me ,how to deploy the code in dev mode and where i execute following lines of code. CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDR ESS=0.0.0.0:30303 ./chaincode_example02 . if run directly ,it show follwing message --->'CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Comment: I concur with the answer provided by Sakaar Bhatia which addresses the above comment.  Navigating into the Docker container for the peer and then running the command is the key.